# Laravel 3 tables model relation construction

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello I have the following 3 tables that are related to each other with ids as follows , I am trying to create a model in Laravel for each but I am confused in to how to use belongsTo & others...

```
 TABLE: posts
 -----------------------------
 id        Auto-inc
 type_id   if (3 its for a blog)
 title 
 content

 TABLE: blog
 -----------------------------
 id        Auto-inc
 post_id   the post id
 cat_id    blog_cat table id 
 slug


 TABLE:blog_cat
 -----------------------------
 id    Auto-inc
 cat_name
```

Now I am trying to write the model for Blog.php , BlogCat.php & Post.php , where I can use something like this :

```
$blog = Post::with('blogCat')->get()->toArray();
```

to get an array with the post & if type_id = 3 ( blog) to get also an array of the blog info from the blog table is this possible or I just need to use select , where / Join?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Blog model, you need a cat() relationship that returns a BelongsTo().

In your Post Model, you need a blog() relationship that returns a HasOne().

To get a collection of Posts with Blogs eager-loaded:

```
$blog = Post::with('blog')->get()
```

To get a collection of Posts with Blogs eager-loaded and BlogCats eager-loaded for each Blog:

```
$blog = Post::with('blog.blogCat')->get()
```

In order to only load Blog for Posts with a type_id of 3, you need to use an "[eager load constraint](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading)"

Comment: BelongTo() what exactly I am confused here?

Comment: You said Blog model and your example says Post::with('blog')

Comment: do you mean this $blog = Blog::with('post')->get()->toArray();

Comment: @user3150060 I edited the post to clarify. And no, you don't need to use ToArray(). ToArray() will transform a model into an array of attributes. get() returns a Collection which acts like an Array. I suggest reading the page that I linked to in full to get an understanding of relationships.

Comment: could you construct the Blog and cat model for me?